# sum of combinations rows (2 rows) in dataframe without repetitions

Tags: r, apply

It is necessary to “increase” the data frame by adding each line from each rows (combinations without repetitions) and writing the result to a new data frame. The result is a huge number of lines compared to the original data frame, so I would like to do without a cycle, deciding, for example, with apply. Data frame for example:

```
1 3 6  
2 2 4  
5 1 2  
6 4 1
```

The result should be:

```
1 3 6  
2 2 4  
5 1 2  
6 4 1  
3 5 10  
6 4 8        
7 7 7        
7 3 6   
8 6 5  
11 5 3
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please include in your question your attempts. What have you tried? What issues did you find when trying that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `combn` and generate combination of row numbers taking 2 at a time, add a custom function to add those rows and bind them with the original dataframe.

```
rbind(df, do.call("rbind",
       combn(1:nrow(df), 2, function(x) df[x[1], ] + df[x[2], ], simplify = FALSE)))


#   V1 V2 V3
#1   1  3  6
#2   2  2  4
#3   5  1  2
#4   6  4  1
#11  3  5 10
#23  6  4  8
#32  7  7  7
#21  7  3  6
#22  8  6  5
#31 11  5  3
```

FYI, the key part here is

```
combn(1:nrow(df), 2) #which gives
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    1    1    1    2    2    3
#[2,]    2    3    4    3    4    4
```

and this input is used to subset rows from original data frame.

Comment: Thank. Functions  "do.call" and "rbind" have the shortest running time in this example? Is there a faster solution?

Comment: @КолчинАндрей As the dataframe size increases the number of rows to be generated will keep on increasing. We can also use `bind_rows` function from `dplyr`, `combn(1:nrow(df), 2, function(x) df[x[1], ] + df[x[2], ], simplify = FALSE) %>%
  bind_rows(df)`